# How can I make a counter-clockwise rotation of the image in java?

Tags: java, image, graphics2d

I have an image and I want it to move in a counter-clockwise direction and that is my problem. I have a code but it seems my code doesn't work properly. You can check my code if where I've made my mistakes. Please help me regarding this matter...

This is my code:

```
public void move(long dt)
{

    double dt_s = dt / 1e9;
    double dx_m = speed * dt_s;
    double dy_m = speed * dt_s;

    double width = board.x1_world;
    double height = board.y1_world;

    double min_height = 0.0;
    double max_height = height;
    double min_width = 0.0;
    double max_width = width;

    x += dx_m;
    if (x >= max_width)
    {
        x = max_width;

        if (y >= min_height)
        {
            y += dy_m;
        }
    }
    if (y >= max_height)
    {
        y = max_height;
        if (x >= min_width)
        {
            dx_m *= -1;
        }
    }
    if (x <= min_width)
    {
        x = min_width;
        if (y <= max_height)
        {
            y -= dy_m;
        }
    }
    if (y <= min_height)
    {
        y = min_height;
        if (x <= max_width)
        {
            dx_m *= -1;
        }
    }


}


@Override
public void render(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    AffineTransform t = g2d.getTransform();

    double height = 0.3;//meter
    double width = 0.3;//meter

    double bird_footy = height;
    double bird_footx = width / 2;


    int xx = board.convertToPixelX(x - bird_footx);
    int yy = board.convertToPixelY(y + bird_footy);

    g2d.translate(xx, yy);

    double x_expected_pixels = width * board.meter;
    double y_expected_pixels = height * board.meter;

    double x_s = x_expected_pixels / ((ToolkitImage) birdImage).getWidth();

    double y_s = y_expected_pixels / ((ToolkitImage) birdImage).getHeight();

    g2d.scale(x_s, y_s);
    g2d.drawImage(getImage(), 0, 0, this);

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g2d.setTransform(t);
}
```

Comment: And where is your image?

Comment: Where does this code comes from? At first sight, it's not code related to any rotation stuff, and it's full of bugs... Moreover, please be more specific when you say it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to rotate the image or make a sprite move in a circular fashion?  I initially thought the former, but your code example suggests the latter.

Comment: @Konstantin Do I really need to put the image in my post? I got only a problem in my move method.

Comment: @Adamski yeah, I want it to move in a circular movement.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For an SSCCE that uses images, generate them in the code.

Comment: @Andrew I just edited my code, I just want also to ask if you're the one who make the SSCCE cause I saw your name there?

Comment: I wrote the SSCCE document, yes.  How about you read it?  What you posted is **not** an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

there you go:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

class RT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("input-image.png"));

        BufferedImage rotated = new AffineTransformOp(
                AffineTransform.getQuadrantRotateInstance(
                    3, img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2),
                AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR).filter(img, null);

        ImageIO.write(rotated, "PNG", new File("output-image.png"));
    }
}
```

- *load* your image as `BufferedImage` through `ImageIO` helper methods
- create an `AffineTransformOp` object, and give it a rotate instance transformation, preferably an `QuadrantRotateInstance` as you're interested in rotating by *90°* exactly. `3` there means 3 quadrants, so three times rotation of 90° each; that equals to one counter-clockwise rotation.
- pass your prefered *quality factor*, usually chosen is `BILINEAR` method, which is semi-fast and semi-good-quality.
- `filter` your transform; that is, apply it to the image. A filtering returns a new `BufferedImage` or it stores the new image in the second argument given to `filter` (`null` above - we store the image in a new `BufferredImage` object)
- `write` or save your image to a file.

*Notes*:
This is a very quick example on how you can do an efficient 90° transform. It's not the only way ofcourse. Take this code and fit it to yours. Make sure to correctly handle *exceptions* (unlike my example).
Read more on the *javadoc* about each of those objects if you want to know more.

---

### Woops

yeah, sooo, I see that - after reading the code of OP - that this is *unrelated* actually, cause the OP seems to want a ***visual*** rotation, not just to rotate an image and present it.
I'll leave this here, if anyone bumps into this question and is looking for this.
For the rest, *ignore it* please.